# adjust auto suggestion list just below the textbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the input element, on which if I type anything, it automatically suggest me some strings.

Input Box Code

```
<div class="col-md-3 flex flex-end menu-suggestion-container">
<input type="text" value="">
<i class="fa fa-plus bg-golden color-white add-menu-icon flex all-center border-radius-50 cur-pointer"></i>
</div>
```

Suggestion List Code

```
<div class="col-md-3 flex flex-end menu-suggestion-container">
<input type="text" value="b">
<ul class="suggestions">
<li class="suggestion-active">Bask</li>
<li>Beer</li>
</ul>
<i class="fa fa-plus bg-golden color-white add-menu-icon flex all-center border-radius-50 cur-pointer"></i>
</div>
```

The desired result would be the suggestion list starts just below the input box. I used absolute positioning with the list but somehow it didn't give the desired output.

CSS For List

```
.menu-suggestion-container .suggestions {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using !important in front of positioning. This "!important" keyword when used makes the browser to use the css method which is marked important explicitely. Try using it.

```
.menu-suggestion-container .suggestions {
 position: absolute; !important
 bottom: 0px;
 background-color: red;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: absolute position is working. I think there is no need of adding !important.